# Java 8 -Two interfaces contain default methods with the same method signature but different return types, how to override?

Tags: java, interface, java-8, overriding, default-method

I understand that if a class implements multiple interfaces containing default methods of same name, then we need to override that method in the child class so as to explicitly define what my method will do.
Problem is, see the below code :

```
interface A {
    default void print() {
        System.out.println(" In interface A ");
    }
}

interface B {
    default String print() {
        return "In interface B";
    }
}

public class C implements A, B {

    @Override
    public String print() {
        return "In class C";
    }

    public static void main(String arg[]) {
        // Other funny things
    }
}
```

Now interface A and B both have a default method with name 'print' but I want to override the print method of interface B - the one that returns a string and leave A's print as is. But this code doesn't compile giving this :

```
Overrides A.print
The return type is incompatible with A.print()
```

Clearly compiler is trying to override A's print method, and I have no idea why !

Comment: wild idea: change the order of the "implements" list

Comment: @flowtron My first intuition was the same, doesn't work.

Comment: maybe a class implementing A and defining its print as **final** could get you there .. another wild and hack-y idea.

Comment: @flowtron Ofcourse there must be some other way around this, but I was wondering why this functionality is designed this way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible.

[8.4.8.3](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.8.4):

> If a method declaration `d1` with return type `R1` overrides or hides the declaration of another method `d2` with return type `R2`, then `d1` must be *return-type-substitutable* for `d2`, or a compile-time error occurs.

[8.4.5](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.5):

> A method declaration `d1` with return type `R1` is *return-type-substitutable* for another method `d2` with return type `R2` iff any of the following is true:
>
> - If `R1` is `void` then `R2` is `void`.
> - If `R1` is a primitive type then `R2` is identical to `R1`.
> - If `R1` is a reference type then one of the following is true:
>
>   - `R1`, adapted to the type parameters of `d2`, is a subtype of `R2`.
>   - `R1` can be converted to a subtype of `R2` by unchecked conversion.
>   - `d1` does not have the same signature as `d2`, and `R1 = |R2|`.

In other words, `void`, primitive- and reference-returning methods may only override and be overridden by methods of that same respective category. A `void` method may only override another `void` method, a reference-returning method may only override another reference-returning method, and so on.

One possible solution to the problem you're having could be to use composition instead of inheritance:

```
class C {
    private A a = ...;
    private B b = ...;
    public A getA() { return a; }
    public B getB() { return b; }
}
```

Comment: My main concern was to override the 'print()' method of interface B, your mentioned links do make it very clear that : 
`It is a compile-time error if a class C inherits a concrete method whose signature is override-equivalent with another method inherited by C.`

So I understand 'what' happens but the 'why' is still not clear ! Why can't the compiler identify by the method's signature that I am overriding interface B's print( ) method. Or if you could give me some insight why this is a bad practice ?

Comment: The language just doesn't allow for two methods to have the same signature but different return types, except when one return type is assignable to the other. You can't declare both a method `void m()` and a method `String m()` in the same class. I don't think there's a technical reason this is impossible for the class file format or JVM. The language designers just decided not to allow it because a method call like `m()` without an assignment is ambiguous with respect to which method is being called.

Comment: Yeah seems logical, thanks for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: @Radiodef: It *is* possible in the class file format. So yes, there is no technical reason.

Comment: @RamanVerma: since Java doesn’t even allow the class `C` to implement `A` and `B` at the same time, it is irrelevant, whether it could identify which method you’re overriding. The reason is that it can not identify which method you’re *invoking* when saying `someInstanceOfC.print()`, at least not without changing the language rules in a way, the Java designers do not want.

Comment: @Holger I could not understand why that is not "exposed" too, but only possible inside the JVM

Comment: @Eugene: to me, it looks consistent to all other design decisions of the original Java language, to make it simple and less error-prone. Even in the current version where target typing exist, choosing among different methods based on the expected return type doesn’t feel like a good idea.

Comment: Just to add one more aspect: choosing a method based on return type certainly doesn't gell well with covariant return types. Inheriting a method returning `Number` and another one returning `Integer` would create rather obscure problems. What if you override the `Integer`-returning method, would that automatically override also the `Number`-returning method, or will you end up with two methods? I'm very happy that this mess is not supported.